# Get previous row value in dataset with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Python and Pandas and I'm trying to get the value of a row in a dataset and the previous one, for example:

```
data["increment"] = data.apply(lambda column: foo(column.A, column.B, column.PREVIOUS_A_VALUE), axis=1)
```

When I said PREVIOUS_A_VALUE is where I want to pass to my function the previous value of A row.

Here is the dataset:

```
A  B
1  10
2  20
3  31
4  45
...
```

For example, when I got the 2 value in my function `foo()` I want to get the value 1 too.

Comment: Hint: you are probably searching for `shift`...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I know about shift, but I want to use the current value in the lambda function and the previous one using `apply()`

Answer (score 0):

@Serge Ballesta referenced the shift function. I would make the increment column the shifted version of A and then overwrite it with your apply:

```
data['increment'] = data.A.shift(-1)
data['increment'] = data.apply(lambda column: foo(column.A, column.B, column.increment), axis=1)
```

Comment: Okey, maybe my question wasn't propertly explained, I want the previous value of the `increment` value

Comment: Like `increment[n] = foo(A ,B, increment[n -1])`? My answer should give `increment[n] = foo(A, B, A[n-1])`.